# How to change the screen orientation during automated testing?

Tags: android, orientation

I am testing my Android application using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, and I need to test that the screen orientation change works correctly. However, I cannot find any way to cause an orientation to occur. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example where I tried extending Android ActivityInstrumentationTestsCase2 to use different screen orientations: [iliasbartolini / AgileDayConferenceApp](https://github.com/iliasbartolini/AgileDayConferenceApp/blob/master/AgileDayConferenceAppTest/src/it/agileday/test/utils/ActivityInstrumentationOrientedScreenTestCase.java)

Basically you need to change the Resources configuration. I found this example here: [Tip for unit-testing: loading Resources for a specific screen orientation/](http://7artstudio.com/androblog/2011/05/14/tip-for-unit-testing-loading-resources-for-a-specific-screen-orientation/)

```
Resources res = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources();
Configuration oldResourcesConfiguration = res.getConfiguration();
Configuration newConfiguration = new Configuration(oldResourcesConfiguration);
newConfiguration.orientation = configurationOrientation;
res.updateConfiguration(newConfiguration, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

[Here is a dummy Landscape test example](https://github.com/iliasbartolini/AgileDayConferenceApp/blob/master/AgileDayConferenceAppTest/src/it/agileday/ui/sessions/ScheduleActivityLandscapeTest.java) on how to use it.

It actually only checks that the Landscape layout and resources loaded by the activity are not broken: don't know if there are better ways to do it.

[And here the Portrait test](https://github.com/iliasbartolini/AgileDayConferenceApp/blob/master/AgileDayConferenceAppTest/src/it/agileday/ui/sessions/ScheduleActivityPortraitTest.java)

Comment: Cool -- I haven't had a chance to try it out yet (I've moved onto a completely different project), but the links look very promising.